# Python - I read a file but it shows me erroneous values?

Tags: python

```
def showCounts(fileName):
    lineCount = 0
    wordCount = 0
    numCount = 0
    comCount = 0
    dotCount = 0

    with open(fileName, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            for char in line:
                if char.isdigit() == True:
                    numCount+=1
                elif char == '.':
                    dotCount+=1
                elif char == ',':
                    comCount+=1
#i know formatting below looks off but it's right
            words = line.split()
            lineCount += 1
            wordCount += len(words)

            for word in words:
#                text = word.translate(string.punctuation)
                exclude = set(string.punctuation)
            text = ""
            text = ''.join(ch for ch in text if ch not in exclude)
            try:
                if int(text) >= 0 or int(text) < 0:
                    numCount += 1
            except ValueError:
                pass

print("Line count: " + str(lineCount))
print("Word count: " + str(wordCount))
print("Number count: " + str(numCount))
print("Comma count: " + str(comCount))
print("Dot  count: " + str(dotCount) + "\n")
```

I have it read a .txt file containing words, lines, dots, commas, and numbers. It will give me the correct number of dots commas and numbers, but the words and lines values will be each much much higher than they actually are. Any one know why? Thanks guys.

Comment: open your text file in `notepad++` and enable viewing special characters. Then see the number of newlines there. If it doesn't match, there is an issue.

Comment: it doesn't match..ugh

Comment: Where is `string` defined? You call `string.punctuation` in your 3rd `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is actually the answer, but my reputation isn't high enough to comment, so I'm putting it here. You obviously don't need to accept it as the final answer if it doesn't solve the issue.

So, I think it might have something to do with the fact that all of your `print` statements are actually outside of the `showCounts()` function. Try indenting the `print` statements.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I'm actually primarily a C/C++ person, so it actually took me a minute to see it. Silly Python and its indentation dependence. :P

Comment: Lol, yep, but most of the slightly confusing syntax in C/C++ is not in python, so indenting matters a heck of a lot more :)

Comment: Definitely true. I like Python, too, I just have less experience with it. Maybe I just like it because I'm such a Monty Python fan. xD

Comment: Yes, that definitely must be it :D

Comment: Thanks for all the responses - unfortunately they are indented in my code and i forgot to indent them when posting the question. As a result, stuck with the same weird numbers for number of lines and number of words :(

Comment: Ah. Damn. I'll look at it some more, but I'm not a Python expert, so I can't promise I'll find anything.